# OpenFoam Mapped Boundary condition

Tags: boundary-conditions, openfoam

I am using OpenFoam to do an LES simulation. I am using mapped boundary condition on the inlet plane. I know it maps from a source plane to the target plane(here the inlet plane). In "Pitzdaily-mapped" tutorial, we only have "set average" and "average" options and there's no option for selecting the source plane. Can anyone please explain how we can specify the plane from which we want to map?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specified in the `blockMeshDict`. So it is a property of the patch itself.

For `pitzDailyMapped` we have the following in the `blockMeshDict`.

```
inlet
{
    type mappedPatch;
    offset          ( 0.0495 0 0 );
    ...
}
```

So the sampling plane is located 0.0495 downstream of the inlet in the x direction.